# From application_helper.rb to own module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails app(3.2.14) I have in `application_helper.rb` methods for converting and parsing strings, integers into USD currency, like (3000 to '30.00' or '0.99' to 99 etc.). They use `number_with_precision` method from `number_helper.rb` - standart rails helper.

The problem is I want to bring all of them into module located `/lib` folder, but I loose rails context.

So how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have your configuration setup to auto-load the lib directory, by default it is not autoloaded by rails

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

then use `include Module` in your lib files (as phoet explained), or use longer include syntax http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers.html -

`include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`

Answer (score 1):

You require the specific helper from actionpack like

```
require 'action_view/helpers/number_helper'
```

and use it in your code

```
include NumberHelper
```